# Apex Trigger - Compile error

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error, compile

I would like compile my apex triggers, but I receveive the following errors.
Same message when i would like deploy apex on my production... :[ (i'm administrator, not dev).

Could you help me please ?

Compilation terminée

```
line 7, column 32: Field is not writeable:ContactShare.ContactAccessLevel
line 7, column 32: Field is not writeable: ContactShare.ContactId
line 7, column 32: Field is not writeable: ContactShare.UserOrGroupId
line 18, column 9: DML operation Insert not allowed on List<ContactShare>
line 36, column 9: DML operation Delete not allowed on List<ContactShare>
```

adding code :

```
public without sharing class IntervenantSurLeContactTriggerClass {
public static void insertIntervenant(List<IntervenantSurLeContact__c> newList){
    Id currentUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    List<ContactShare> sharesToInsert = new List<ContactShare>();
    List<IntervenantSurLeContact__Share> sharesSharesToInsert = new List<IntervenantSurLeContact__Share>();
    for(IntervenantSurLeContact__c isc : newList){
        sharesToInsert.add(new ContactShare(ContactAccessLevel = 'Edit', ContactId = isc.Contact__c, UserOrGroupId = isc.Utilisateur__c));
        if(currentUserId != isc.Utilisateur__c){
            IntervenantSurLeContact__Share interShare = new IntervenantSurLeContact__Share();
            interShare.UserOrGroupId = isc.Utilisateur__c;
            interShare.RowCause = 'Manual';
            interShare.ParentId = isc.Id;
            interShare.AccessLevel = 'Read';
            sharesSharesToInsert.add(interShare);
        }
    }
   
    insert sharesToInsert;
    insert sharesSharesToInsert;
}
public static void deleteIntervenant(List<IntervenantSurLeContact__c> oldList){
    List<ContactShare> contactShareToDelete = new List<ContactShare>();
    Set<String> keyToDelete = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> contactIds = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> userIds = new Set<String>();
    for(IntervenantSurLeContact__c isc : oldList){
        keyToDelete.add(isc.Contact__c + '-' + isc.Utilisateur__c);
        contactIds.add(isc.Contact__c);
        userIds.add(isc.Utilisateur__c);
    }
    for(ContactShare contShare : [SELECT Id, ContactId, UserOrGroupId FROM ContactShare WHERE ContactId IN: contactIds AND UserOrGroupId IN: userIds]){
        if(keyToDelete.contains(contShare.ContactId + '-' + contShare.UserOrGroupId)){
            contactShareToDelete.add(contShare);
        }
    }
    delete contactShareToDelete;
}
```

Regards

Comment: Well, the error messages seem clear enough. About all I think we can say without more information (seeing the code for this trigger and/or Apex classes, knowing the API version it's using, having more information about what purpose the code is supposed to serve/its business case) is that you simply need to remove lines 7, 18, and 36 from this code.

Comment: About the only other thing that I can think of is that this code is trying to assign values to those ContactShare fields (i.e. it uses a single equals sign, `=`) instead of trying to _compare_ those values to something (i.e. using a double equals sign, `==`).

Comment: Wow thanks! Im trying to remove this code. 
It was use while contact was Public in OWD. However, now contact are defined to 'controlled by parents'.
It seems that I can't modify this production code whitout modify the associated owd ?

Comment: Iv added the code to the post

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Given the context added by your comments and edit, I feel the easiest way to move on with your project at the moment is to use *block comments*. These are comments that start with `/*` and end with `*/`.

```java
public without sharing class IntervenantSurLeContactTriggerClass {
public static void insertIntervenant(List<IntervenantSurLeContact__c> newList){
/*
    Id currentUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    List<ContactShare> sharesToInsert = new List<ContactShare>();
    List<IntervenantSurLeContact__Share> sharesSharesToInsert = new List<IntervenantSurLeContact__Share>();
    for(IntervenantSurLeContact__c isc : newList){
        sharesToInsert.add(new ContactShare(ContactAccessLevel = 'Edit', ContactId = isc.Contact__c, UserOrGroupId = isc.Utilisateur__c));
        if(currentUserId != isc.Utilisateur__c){
            IntervenantSurLeContact__Share interShare = new IntervenantSurLeContact__Share();
            interShare.UserOrGroupId = isc.Utilisateur__c;
            interShare.RowCause = 'Manual';
            interShare.ParentId = isc.Id;
            interShare.AccessLevel = 'Read';
            sharesSharesToInsert.add(interShare);
        }
    }
   
    insert sharesToInsert;
    insert sharesSharesToInsert;
*/
}
public static void deleteIntervenant(List<IntervenantSurLeContact__c> oldList){
/*    List<ContactShare> contactShareToDelete = new List<ContactShare>();
    Set<String> keyToDelete = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> contactIds = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> userIds = new Set<String>();
    for(IntervenantSurLeContact__c isc : oldList){
        keyToDelete.add(isc.Contact__c + '-' + isc.Utilisateur__c);
        contactIds.add(isc.Contact__c);
        userIds.add(isc.Utilisateur__c);
    }
    for(ContactShare contShare : [SELECT Id, ContactId, UserOrGroupId FROM ContactShare WHERE ContactId IN: contactIds AND UserOrGroupId IN: userIds]){
        if(keyToDelete.contains(contShare.ContactId + '-' + contShare.UserOrGroupId)){
            contactShareToDelete.add(contShare);
        }
    }
    delete contactShareToDelete;
*/
}
```

If you change the code as above in a Sandbox, you can use a change set to deploy this to production. You may also get "assertion failed" messages in some unit test that covers this code, if you find those, you can just comment out the entire method. Once all references to the share object, and the code that called this code, are removed, you'll be able to deploy those changes.

---

The error has to do with your [Organization Wide Defaults](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_owd_about.htm&language=en_US&type=5). Most likely, you've set your Contact Sharing setting to Controlled By Parent or Public Read/Write, which means that sharing is not applicable in your org. You'll have to either fix the code, or restrict Contact Sharing to a more restrictive model. Without knowing what the code does, it's impossible to say whether Public Read Only or Private would be more appropriate.